# Prime factorisation of ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, prime-factorization

I am concerned with the following proposition:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $I\subsetneqq R$ be a proper ideal. Then there exist prime ideals $P_1,\dots,P_d$ containing $I$ so that $I=P_1 P_2 \cdots P_d$.

The notes that I took down argues as follows. Let $\mathcal S$ be the collection of all proper ideals $I$ for which the above is FALSE. Then there is a maximal element $I\in \mathcal S$. We claim that $I$ is prime. Suppose not. Then there are $a,b\notin I$ with $ab\in I$. Let $J_1:=\langle a \rangle+I$, $J_2:=\langle b \rangle+I$. Then $J_1,J_2$ both strictly contain $I$, and are not in $\mathcal S$ by maximality. Thus $J_1,J_2$ satisfies the factorisation property. Take $P_1,\dots,P_d$ all containing $J_1$ so that $J_1= P_1\cdots P_d$, and take $Q_1,\dots,Q_s$ all containing $J_2$ so that $J_2= Q_1\cdots Q_s$. Then note that
  \begin{align*}
  P_1\cdots P_d\cdot Q_1\cdots Q_s
  &= J_1 J_2=(\langle a \rangle+I)(\langle b \rangle+I)\\
  &=\left\{\sum_{i,j}c_i a d_j b+c_i a s_j+d_j b r_i+ r_i s_j\right\}\\
  &\subseteq I,\text{ since }ab\in I \text{ and $I$ is an ideal}.
  \end{align*}
  Since $I\subsetneqq J_1$, $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$. Since $I$ admits such factorisation as shown, we see that $I\notin \mathcal S$, which is a contradiction. Thus $I$ is prime.

Lastly, since $I$ is prime, take $P_1=I$ so that $I=P_1$ is a trivial factorisation. Hence $I\notin \mathcal S$, which is a contradiction. Thus $\mathcal S=\varnothing$.

The only place where I got stuck is the last line in the computation of $P_1\cdots P_d\cdot Q_1\cdots Q_s$, since it only proves one direction. What about the other direction? Or is such proposition actually false?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was asking whether we can pick $a,b$ to satisfy in addition that $(I,(a))(I,(b))=I$.

Comment: What is the argument for $S$ having a maximal element ? Is it in a Dedekind ring ? Also $(I,(a))(I,(b)) = (I^2,(ab),(a)I,(b)I) \subseteq I$ and you'll probably need to show that if $J=J_1J_2$ has a prime factorization and $J \subseteq I $ then $I = (I,J)$ has a prime factorization.

Comment: I searched the wiki for the definition of Dedekind ring, and found that it is exactly what I would like to prove. Therefore I believe that this proposition is trivially false.

Comment: If $R$ a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite integral domain, thus a field, so that prime ideals are maximals. Using this you should be able to make your proof work.

Comment: Such statement is false. If you have enought background (complete intersection & Gorenstein), please take a look at the paper Ideals defining Gorenstein rings are (almost) never products by C. Huneke. Take a polynomial ring and let $x,y$ be variables. $I = (x^2,y^2)$ cannot have such decoposition.

Comment: Another possible class of examples is $m$-primary ideals in a local ring $(R,m)$. Unless they are already a power of $m$, you may not hope to have such decomposition.